# center all div tags using flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to center all my div tags in the center of the screen, but even after doing text-align: center, I can't center all the nested div tags. Below is the screen that I am trying to center :

[image]

I want "Please upload your file", choose file and drag and drop box all in the center of the screen, but all the elements are not aligned properly. Below is my stylesheet:

```
 .dropArea {
      border: 2px dashed steelblue;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: lightblue;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
       min-height: 200px;
  }

    .dropArea:hover {
        background-color: lightskyblue;
        color: #333;
    }

    .dropArea input[type=file] {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.dropAreaDrug {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
}

.container{

    display:flex;   
    justify-content:center;
}
.child {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

below is my html file:

```
<p>Please <b>upload</b> your file</p>

<div class="container">
    <div class="inputArea ">
        <InputFile id="inputDefault"
                   OnChange="OnInputFileChange"
                   accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
    </div>
    <div class="dropArea  @dropClass">
        Drag and drop your files here or click to open file loading dialogue...
        <InputFile id="inputDrop"
                   OnChange="OnInputFileChange"
                   @ondragenter="HandleDragEnter"
                   @ondragleave="HandleDragLeave"
                   multiple />
    </div>

    @if (files != null && files.Count > 1)
    {
        <div>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    <li>@file.Name</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
    @if (urls.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            <br />
            <a href="@url" download>@url</a>
        }
    }
</div>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your HTML markup, so that anyone can understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align the flex items in your [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) along the main axis using `justify-content: center` and vertically align them along the cross axis with `align-items: center`. Specify `min-height: 100vh` on the `.container` element if you want the flex items to be centered vertically on the page along the cross axis.

Also, your going to want to nest the topmost `<p>` tag inside `.container` or `.inputArea` if you want it to be a flex item and aligned in the same row format. After reading your comments below, you can make the `<p>` text and `<input>` in a column layout by making `.inputArea` a flex container with `flex-direction: column`. Then if you want to restrict the width of the drag/drop container just give it a `max-width` declaration.

```css
.container{
    display:flex;   
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.inputArea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropArea {
      max-width: 500px; /* vary this as you see fit */
      border: 2px dashed steelblue;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: lightblue;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
       min-height: 200px;
  }

    .dropArea:hover {
        background-color: lightskyblue;
        color: #333;
    }

    .dropArea input[type=file] {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.dropAreaDrug {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
}
.child {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inputArea">
    <p>Please <b>upload</b> your file</p>
    <input type="file" />
        <!--<InputFile id="inputDefault"
                   OnChange="OnInputFileChange"
                   accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />-->
    </div>
    <div class="dropArea  @dropClass">
        Drag and drop your files here or click to open file loading dialogue...
        <InputFile id="inputDrop"
                   OnChange="OnInputFileChange"
                   @ondragenter="HandleDragEnter"
                   @ondragleave="HandleDragLeave"
                   multiple />
    </div>

<!--
    @if (files != null && files.Count > 1)
    {
        <div>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    <li>@file.Name</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
    @if (urls.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            <br />
            <a href="@url" download>@url</a>
        }
    }-->
</div>
```

Comment: @cool I just updated my answer with your HTML, does this help answer your question?

Comment: I want everything to be in the center stack in the center. First "Please choose your file" and then beneath it Choose the file button and then drag and drop your files. I want to make the drag and drop file box small so that it can align in the center

Comment: @cool I changed the layout so the "Please choose your file" text sits above the `<input>` element for file upload and then the drag/drop area is on the right? Is there still something more you need?

Comment: Thank You! This is all I need.